# JAVA : Filter all dates which equals and after today

Tags: java, date

i'm trying to check a way to retrieve all the dates which will be equal to the date of today and the future

```
dates.stream().filter(d -> d.equals(new Date()) || d.after(new Date())).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

I need a more efficient solution.

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `Date`. That class is poorly designed and long outdated. Instead use `LocalDate` from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: If the time now is 17:22 and a `Date` representing today at 13:42, then your condition will be false and the date will not be included. `LocalDate` hasn’t got that problem since a `LocalDate` represents just a date, no time of day.

Comment: What makes you think that you need a more efficient solution? How long does filtering take in your current code? Also asking because I don’t readily think of a way to make it faster as your code stands. If you could make sure your dates were sorted beforehand, it would be a different story.

Comment: @OleV.V. i can't use LocalDate

Comment: this code doesn't work

Comment: Either you have got an evil boss that forces you to use Java 5 (or earlier) — or you *can* use `LocalDate`. Which hindrance were you thinking there would be? Of course, if you are getting the `Date` objects from a legacy API or giving them to one, you may not be able to change that. You can still use `LocalDate` in your own code.

Comment: In case it matters (I keep my doubts), you may also be able to find a more efficient solution without streams.

Comment: In what way *doesn’t work*, please? Please paste your incorrect result or your error message into the question so that we may help you with it.

Answer (score 2):

If you really need use `Date` class (instead of recommended `java.time` library), you can just use `compareTo()` method.

```java
Date currentDate = new Date();
dates.stream()
    .filter(date -> date.compareTo(currentDate) >= 0)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

`Date` objects are comparing by their `long` values, so when I use `>=` it means, that `date` is the same or later than `currentDate()`.

Comment: I frankly personally find it less readable and therefore inefficient to maintain. Maybe it can save a few clock cycles.

Comment: You may be right. What you think about `.filter(date -> !date.before(currentDate))` instead of? In fact, I think these three versions are a matter of taste. Nevertheless, I recommend the newer date implementations.

Comment: `!date.before(currentDate)` is fine and probably efficient (we’d have to measure before we know). As you have probably seen, I am with you all the way on the newer classes.